# token this error ( specific code)

Tags: jquery

Giving this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this, 
  Here is my code

```
var resizeMap = function () {

        if (jQuery(this).width() < 600) {
            jQuery(this).addClass("mapvsm");


        } else {
            jQuery(this).addClass("mapvlg");

        }
    };


    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".mapv_container").each(function(this) {
            resizeMap();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Remove `this` from `jQuery(".mapv_container").each(function(this) {`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

pl try this peace of code outside (document).ready function

```
   $(function () {
                resizeMap();
                });
```